# DirectoryInfo.Exists returns true even after the folder has been deleted

Tags: c#

I'm creating a temporary folder which has a folder inside it in a folder that the user chooses when the application starts. I created a delete button that should delete the temporary folders and files created in them when the user is using the application.

I first click delete button and the files and folders are removed, if I click the delete button again the DirectoryInfo.Exist method still returns true even when the folder I'm casting in as a parameter is no longer existing, and due to it being true I get an error because it tries to remove a folder that doesn't exist.

I'm thankful for any help :)

**C#**

```
if (FilePaths.mainDirectory.Exists)
{
    if (DirectoryNotEmpty(FilePaths.mainDirectory.FullName))
    {
        if (DirectoryNotEmpty(FilePaths.actionDirectory.FullName))
        {
            foreach (var file in FilePaths.actionDirectory.GetFiles()) file.Delete();
        }
        Directory.Delete(FilePaths.actionDirectory.FullName);

        foreach (var file in FilePaths.mainDirectory.GetFiles()) file.Delete();
        Directory.Delete(FilePaths.mainDirectory.FullName);
    }
}
```

Here is the instantiation of the DirectoryInfo objects

```
public static string mainFolder = "";
public static string actionFolder = "";
public static DirectoryInfo mainDirectory;
public static DirectoryInfo actionDirectory;

public static void CreateTemporaryFolders()
{
    if (mainFolder != "")
    {
        actionFolder = Path.Combine(mainFolder, "Action Files");

        mainDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(mainFolder);
        actionDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(actionFolder);
    }
}
```

If any more code is needed, just let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DirectoryInfo` is mostly a snapshot; for the reality *right now*, ask `Directory.Exists(string)`, but keep in mind that *any* disk check is inherently a potential race condition (other processes could change the state right after you check).

Comment: Or he could call `DirectoryInfo.Refresh` to get the current state.

Comment: @ckuri true, but if what you're actually *interested in* is "does this exist", `Directory.Exists` involves fewer unnecessary overheads